# Hide Span Value Jquery Value Change OnHover

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I want to hide the value of the span if a condition is met however the span value changes on hover

```
var stocklevel = parseInt($('#inventoryQuantity').text(variant.inventory_quantity));

if(stocklevel < 10)
{
    $('#inventoryQuantity').text(variant.inventory_quantity);
}
else
{

    }
```

but the condition doesnt seem to work because when the value of span changes on mouse hover , it will still display the value higher than 10

```
<h4> <span id="inventoryQuantity">{{current_variant.inventory_quantity }}</span> available. </h4>
```

Comment: Plz share the code that's handling `hover` event. Also, what are the results if you log `stocklevel` in console before and after `hover`?

Comment: im actually trying to override that since the code is hard to find

Comment: In that case, first override/control/change the `hover` event before testing your condition. You may also need to know what specific event is being handled currently i.e. `hover`,`mouseenter`,`mouseleave`, or `mouseover`. Do note that `hover` is shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` both. May be able to help if you can share the current behavior on `hover` i.e. how does it affect  `inventoryQuantity` and does `inventoryQuantity` change back to previous value on `mouseleave`?

Comment: no the value does not change back on mousehover or mouseout

Comment: so basically, `mouseenter` on `inventoryQuantity` changes text from 1 to 2 (just and example) and on `mouseleave` the text stays at 2? is that right?

Comment: yes that is correct but if you hover to another one it will change value but not on mouseleave